# Error while executing kmean using madlib library on Greenplum

Tags: greenplum, hawq, madlib

I am trying to run `kmean` algorithm using `madlib` library, tool used aginity
tried executing :

```
SELECT * FROM madlib.kmeans_random('select "MPrice" as "MPrice" from "madlib"."sample_sordetail"','MPrice',2,'madlib.squared_dist_norm2','madlib.avg',10,0.001)
```

my table name is `sample_sordetail`.

I am getting the error :

> ERROR: XX000: plpy.Error: kmeans error: Data table does not exist!
>   (plpython.c:4648)

Please suggest how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

[madlib_kmean](https://madlib.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/group__grp__kmeans.html)
Please check the kmean_random parameter definition.
rel_source -> TEXT.   You need to put table name here. "select ......from ..." is not a table. 
You should be able to find the tutorial in this madlib website.

Comment: Tried also as per madlib documentaion
CREATE TABLE km_result AS
SELECT * FROM madlib.kmeans_random('madlib.km_sample', 
                                'ARRAY[MPrice]', 
                                2,
                                'madlib.squared_dist_norm2',
                                'madlib.avg', 
                                20, 
                                0.001);
madlib.km_sample is table name and  MPrice is column.

Here I get error CREATE TABLE km_result AS SELECT * FROM madlib.kmean_random('madlib.km_sample, 
ERROR: 42703: column "mprice" does not exist

Comment: mprice column is there in table still I am getting this error. 
I am using Greenplum database 4.3, Madlib 1.9 version
Please suggest

Comment: you need to deal with capital letters in postgres systems. also make sure the schema is in your search_path.

Comment: schema is in my search_path select * from madlib.km_sample gives result

Answer (score 0):

After struggling a lot I got to know the error is due to the data format. 
The MPrice column should have type points double precision[]. 
Reference
http://madlib.incubator.apache.org/docs/master/group__grp__kmeans.html

After changing MPrice to double precision I was able to execute kmean algorithm on the dataset.

Comment: better include explanation within site and avoid external links as much as possible.